# Updateable mysql views

Tags: mysql, workbench

can i have a advise on how to update a views? this is my created views.. but because of stored functions its not updateable right? do the join query did it not updateable too? and the if function? please help me..sorry for my english.

```
CREATE 
    ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
    DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` 
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    VIEW `view_attendance_dgv` AS
    select 
        `tbl_stockholders`.`user_id` AS `user_id`,
        `tbl_images`.`image_template` AS `Image Template`,
        finger_name(`tbl_fingerprints`.`finger`) AS `Enrolled Finger`,
        `tbl_users`.`last_name` AS `Last Name`,
        `tbl_users`.`first_name` AS `First Name`,
        `tbl_users`.`middle_name` AS `Middle Name`,
        if((`tbl_stockholders`.`attendance_status` = 0),
            'Absent',
            'Present') AS `Attendance Status`,
        if((`tbl_stockholders`.`voting_status` = 0),
            'Not Voted',
            'Voted') AS `Voting Status`
    from
        ((((`tbl_stockholders`
        join `tbl_shares` ON ((`tbl_stockholders`.`user_id` = `tbl_shares`.`user_id`)))
        join `tbl_users` ON ((`tbl_stockholders`.`user_id` = `tbl_users`.`user_id`)))
        join `tbl_images` ON ((`tbl_stockholders`.`user_id` = `tbl_images`.`user_id`)))
        join `tbl_fingerprints` ON ((`tbl_stockholders`.`user_id` =         `tbl_fingerprints`.`user_id`)))
    order by `tbl_stockholders`.`user_id`
```

Comment: Please read this documentation page http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/view-updatability.html with special attention to `It is sometimes possible for a multiple-table view to be updatable, assuming that it can be processed with the MERGE algorithm. For this to work, the view must use an inner join (not an outer join or a UNION). Also, only a single table in the view definition can be updated, so the SET clause must name only columns from one of the tables in the view.`

Answer (score 2):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-view.html

> For a view to be updatable, there must be a one-to-one relationship between the rows in the view and the rows in the underlying table. There are also certain other constructs that make a view nonupdatable.

More details are here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/view-updatability.html

Yes, I believe in your query, your use of `JOIN`s and functions makes your view non-updatable.